# DigitalDJ / AudioStreamer not connect to streaming server

Tags: iphone, ios, audiostreamer

I downloaded the code DigitalDJ / AudioStreamer to use in a player I'm doing, here's the project that I downloaded: https://github.com/DigitalDJ/AudioStreamer

Have used this library before I decided to upgrade it supports multi-thread,

but when I change the address of the streaming server http:// thor.nickpack.com:9000 to the address of my server, it does not run the audio.

to replace the server path that is in a TextField in viewController to my path: http:// 184.154.37.132:7075 see my problem.

Another solution would be to modify the old player that supports multi thread, I've tried several codes and could not, that was when I found the DigitalDJ / AudioStreamer, but I came across the problem I mentioned above,

this is the link for a sample app that does not have multi thread: http://www.mediafire.com/?eb7a6a87e8tqcbc

if someone has a clue how to implement audio in backgorund or how to solve the problem of streaming server I am grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a long time and almost going crazy trying to solved the problem by commenting the code in this trexo AudioStreamer.m

```
// hintForMIMEType
//
// Make a more informed guess on the file type based on the MIME type
//
// Parameters:
//    mimeType - the MIME type
//
// returns a file type hint that can be passed to the AudioFileStream
//
/*
+ (AudioFileTypeID)hintForMIMEType:(NSString *)mimeType
{
    AudioFileTypeID fileTypeHint = kAudioFileMP3Type;
    if ([mimeType isEqual:@"audio/mpeg"])
    {
        fileTypeHint = kAudioFileMP3Type;
    }
    else if ([mimeType isEqual:@"audio/x-wav"])
    {
        fileTypeHint = kAudioFileWAVEType;
    }
    else if ([mimeType isEqual:@"audio/x-aiff"])
    {
        fileTypeHint = kAudioFileAIFFType;
    }
    else if ([mimeType isEqual:@"audio/x-m4a"])
    {
        fileTypeHint = kAudioFileM4AType;
    }
        else if ([mimeType isEqual:@"audio/mp4"])
    {
        fileTypeHint = kAudioFileMPEG4Type;
    }
        else if ([mimeType isEqual:@"audio/x-caf"])
    {
        fileTypeHint = kAudioFileCAFType;
    }
        else if ([mimeType isEqual:@"audio/aac"] || [mimeType isEqual:@"audio/aacp"])
    {
        fileTypeHint = kAudioFileAAC_ADTSType;
    }
    return fileTypeHint;
 }*/
```

with this code commented out the audio played without problems on my server

Answer (score 0):

I had problems connecting to MP3 stream with AudioStreamer. The sample would work on Simulator but not on device. I think because simulator isnt exact copy of ios device. On Simulator it uses the quicktime installed on the mac.

For local MP3 files use AVAudioPlayer.

For remote MP3 streams Use AVPlayer.

A good sample project is at

```
https://github.com/valvoline/CPStreamPlayer
```

Often remote streams take time to connect to time out. This sample shows that its buffering.

Search Github for AVPlayer theres a few samples.

CPStreamPlayer/AVPlayer supports redirects so for us we had

```
http://stream.fireplayer.com/greyhound/dyn?action=stream.StreamMix&id=1785
```

BUT THIS REDIRECTED TO GENERATE Mp3 file/stream on Amazon

```
http://s3.amazonaws.com/fireplayer_mp3/1785.mp3?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJAHV5HUV4TVRF5VA&Expires=1337595252&Signature=c%2FH%2FO9AACkovm%2BAhbWyD7E9Hb6A%3D";
```